WalletConnect not working on Safari (iOS)
I have the below code as a custom action in flutter flow that is triggered when a user clicks a button. The functionality works fine on Android as well as on Chrome on iOS - the user gets an option to open in MetaMask and can approve a new session. However, nothing happens when the user clicks the button on Safari on iOS.
// Automatic FlutterFlow imports
import '/backend/backend.dart';
import '/backend/schema/structs/index.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_util.dart';
import '/custom_code/actions/index.dart'; // Imports other custom actions
import '/flutter_flow/custom_functions.dart'; // Imports custom functions
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// Begin custom action code
// DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THE CODE ABOVE!

import 'package:walletconnect_flutter_v2/walletconnect_flutter_v2.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart' as url_launcher;
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

Future<bool> connectWalletMob(BuildContext context) async {
  Web3App? _web3App;
  String? _account;
  SessionData? _session;
  bool _isInitialized = false;

  // Initialize Web3App
  try {
    _web3App = await Web3App.createInstance(
      projectId: 'b25f3e3ec507a094e791f8b18de4be5f',
      metadata: const PairingMetadata(
        name: 'Qache App',
        description: 'An app for pooling Ethereum staking yield',
        url: 'https://qache-app.flutterflow.app/',
        icons: ['https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/37784886'],
      ),
    );
    _isInitialized = true;
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error initializing Web3App: $e');
    return false;
  }

  // Launch Wallet App
  Future<void> _launchWalletApp(Uri uri) async {
    final url =
        'https://metamask.app.link/wc?uri=${Uri.encodeComponent(uri.toString())}';
    final Uri parsedUrl = Uri.parse(url);
    if (await url_launcher.canLaunchUrl(parsedUrl)) {
      await url_launcher.launchUrl(parsedUrl);
    } else {
      print('Could not launch $url');
    }
  }

  // Connect Wallet Function
  Future<void> _connectWallet() async {
    if (!_isInitialized) {
      print('Web3App not initialized');
      return;
    }

    try {
      final ConnectResponse resp = await _web3App!.connect(
        requiredNamespaces: {
          'eip155': RequiredNamespace(
            chains: ['eip155:1'],
            methods: ['eth_sendTransaction', 'personal_sign'],
            events: ['chainChanged', 'accountsChanged'],
          ),
        },
      );

      if (resp.uri != null) {
        await _launchWalletApp(resp.uri!);
      } else {
        print('No URI received');
      }

      _session = await resp.session.future;

      if (_session != null && _session!.namespaces.containsKey('eip155')) {
        final accounts = _session!.namespaces['eip155']?.accounts ?? [];
        if (accounts.isNotEmpty) {
          _account = accounts.first.split(':').last;
          print('Connected: $_account');
        } else {
          print('No accounts received');
        }
      } else {
        print('No eip155 namespace in session');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error connecting wallet: $e');
    }
  }

  // Call connect wallet function
  await _connectWallet();

  // Update database
  if (_account != null && _session != null) {
    try {
      // Get the current user's ID
      String? userId = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid;

      if (userId != null) {
        // Update Firestore
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .doc(userId)
            .update({
          'walletAddress': _account,
          'sessionTopic': _session!.topic,
        });

        return true; // Connection and database update successful
      } else {
        print('Current user ID is null');
        return false;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error updating database: $e');
      return false;
    }
  } else {
    print('Failed to connect wallet');
    return false;
  }
}

Couldn't find a solution that works on Safari on iOS
